# Я чутка чайничек пытался сделать, но не получилось.Переменные if

Tags: python

В общем такое дело, мне нужно сделать, так.
Если a>39
Скрипт
Если а<38
Error

---

Там будет длинный скрипт, что делать не просто print()

Answer (score 2):

```py
def script():
    print('Длинный скрипт')  # Эту строку, естественно, можно удалить
    # Пишите тут Ваш длинный скрипт


def main():
    a = int(input())

    if a >= 39:
        script()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'{a} ∉ [39, +∞]')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: а разве так не лучше? print([script() if a > 39 else False])

Comment: Там  длинный скрипт при a => 39

Comment: @Toxenskiy Вынесите его в отдельный пакет/модуль/функцию и запустите. В чём конкретно Вы видите проблему?

Comment: Как вынести в пакет/модуль/функцию

Comment: @Toxenskiy Обновил ответ, создав отдельную функцию. Но если честно, советовал бы Вам подучить основы `Python`, чтобы не возникали подобные вопросы.

Comment: Не работает. Пробовал

Comment: @Toxenskiy Что не работает и что Вы пробовали?

Comment: Я сделал по другому, функцию скрипта взял и всё, а с if elif сам разобрался.